# Firebase DynamicLink Url returning jSON serialize error. iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Xcode version: 10.1
Firebase SDK version: 6.0.0
Firebase Component: Firebase/DynamicLinks
Component version: 4.0.0

Hi, I am stuck at a point when dealing with Dynamic linking, all is good when making a link, but i am getting error on the link which is like this

```
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>
```

and link which is generated https://marcoapp.page.link/T4Ye is here which is having issue.
i know that is error where someone would say it's from backend , but no same things worked before and even Android level of application is still working fine with same parameters. And i didn't get what is wrong thing i am sending or not sending which is causing this issue. Below mentioned is the code.

```
 guard let components: DynamicLinkComponents = DynamicLinkComponents(link: urlLink, domainURIPrefix: "https://marcoapp.page.link") else {
                return ""
            }
```

in here urlLink = https://marcotest.azurewebsites.net/api/Groups/(Int)

Answer (score 0):

```
func createDynamicLink() {

    let domain = "yourProject.page.link"

    let link = URL(string: "https://facebook.com")
    let referralLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link!, domain: domain)

    referralLink.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: “set_app_bundleID")
    referralLink.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "app_store_id"
    referralLink.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "set_app_bundleID")


    guard let longUrl = referralLink.url?.absoluteString else {
        return
    }

    print(longUrl)
}
```

> Make sure you have already created domain in **firebase account** in **Dynamic links** section then only you can use  let domain = "yourProject.page.link"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA6SL.jpg

Comment: yess i made it also, i told you it was working fine before. i have done all as same